# How to Skip a stage in a jenkins pipeline Build based on a Jenkins trigger

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

Is there any way to skip certain stages after a GitLab webhook is triggered?

Here is my JenkinsFile:

[image]

and here are the triggers I set for this pipeline:

[image]

Now what I would like as a result is this:

**1) For the 3rd stage (push docker image to docker registry) and 4th stage (check&run) to be skipped when the merge request is opened.**

**2) For the whole pipeline to run completely when the merge request is accepted.**

I cannot seem to figure it out or any work-around to do it.

P.S : it shall be a simple pipeline project (I don't want to use a multi-branch project)

Answer (score 0):

Build `Cause` is storred in hudson [Cause](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Cause.html) class. What you can do is to add a `script` block to your declarative pipeline, get current build, get the `Cause`.

Cause is something like this, when viewed in basic jenkins UI:

[image]

Once you have the `Cause` you can do `getShortDescription()` on it to get the event that triggered the build. On base of that you can run your stages.

To get build causes from current build you need a scripted step like this:

```
script {
   def isMergeRequest = currentBuild.getBuildCauses()
}
```

**Edit:**

Apparently this can be done much easier, using the declarative built-in `triggeredBy` [(official docs)](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#built-in-conditions):

```
when { triggeredBy cause: "build-cause", detail: "detail" }
```

With this you don't need to extract the cause you can simply add it to your stage like this:

```
stage("trigger on condition") {

    when { triggeredBy cause: "UserIdCause", detail: "vlinde" }

    steps {
        ...some steps
    }
}
```

The cause should match something that is returned by scm when pull request is created and accepted (to fit your expectations).

**Edit 2:**

So since we didn't get the status in our `triggeredBy` cause, the only other thing I can think of is to use `generic webhook plugin` for Jenkins. It can be found [here](https://plugins.jenkins.io/generic-webhook-trigger/). It can parse the webhook payload and extract something from it using `jsonpath`, then set it as an `env` variable that we can use in pipeline script.

According to [official docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhook_events.html#merge-request-events) `gitlab` merge request has this information in payload:

> The available values for `object_attributes.action` in the payload are:
>
> open, close, reopen, update, approved, unapproved, approval, unapproval, merge

So while using the `generic webhook plugin` you could extract the information about an event using this `jsonpath`:

`object_attributes.action`

set it to a variable name of your choice and based on that, run your stages.

Comment: Can you please be more specific on how i can use the Cause in my case ?

Comment: thank you for your interraction i tried to see what matches the scm return when the pull request is created and accepted and it gives me this : [[_class:com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.cause.GitLabWebHookCause, shortDescription:Triggered by GitLab Merge Request #6: Ayoub ELKASS/test => main]] 

i seems that jenkins cant differentiate when the pull request is created and when it is accepted .. or im i getting it wrong?

Comment: I have updated my question, this should help with identifying the details behind gitlab merge